# What is C# equivalent of geography sql server datatype in .net framework 4.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, .net-4.0

net web application using .net 4.0 framework.

I have a Stored Procedure which accepts geography datatype in sql server 2008 R2.

I want to insert data from C# code into SQL Server.

But I'm not able to find which datatype I should use in C# that is equivalent to SQL Server 2008 datatype.

Comment: I would assume byte[].  Depends if you are using ADO.NET, Entity Framework, etc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are using entity-framework then the datatype you search is DbGeography.

Here is some more information about DbGeography object -> [Details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.spatial.dbgeography?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.0).

Comment: DbGeography is in the System.Data.Entity namespace, which is Entity Framework...  I don't know that he's using that...

Answer (score 10):

It may sound obvious, but why not use the same data type that has been installed as a UDT in SQL Server - [`SqlGeography`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.types.sqlgeography%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)?

The following works fine against a SQL Server 2012 instance. I'm unable to test against SQL Server 2008 but I'd assume it should work the same:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Types;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var geom1 = SqlGeography.STGeomFromText(
                        new System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlChars(
                        "LINESTRING(-122.360 47.656, -122.343 47.656)"), 4326);
            var geom2 = SqlGeography.STGeomFromText(
                        new System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlChars(
                        "LINESTRING(-100.0 45.0, -1420 49.0)"), 4326);
            using(var conn = new SqlConnection(
                  @"Server=Server;Database=master;Integrated Security=SSPI;"))
            {
                using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(
                    "select @parm1.STIntersects(@parm2)", conn))
                {
                    var p1 = cmd.Parameters.Add("@parm1", SqlDbType.Udt);
                    p1.UdtTypeName = "geography";
                    p1.Value = geom1;
                    var p2 = cmd.Parameters.Add("@parm2", SqlDbType.Udt);
                    p2.UdtTypeName = "geography";
                    p2.Value = geom2;
                    conn.Open();
                    Console.WriteLine(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: If you are using EntityFramework, then you should use `DbGeography` for your model properties which uses `SqlGeography` _under the hood_

Comment: @ChrisSchaller - that is already covered in other answers and there's still no indication in the question that the OP *was* using EF or not.

Answer (score 2):

Isn't it the `DbGeography` class?

Namespace:  System.Data.Spatial
Assembly:  System.Data.Entity (in System.Data.Entity.dll)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.spatial.dbgeography.aspx